# Can I fill time in R?

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate

I have this dataframe that has date_time in it. the original dataframe is way bigger that I cannot check all the observations to make sure it has the right time sequence in it.

```
dataframe<- structure(list(Date_Time = structure(1:5, .Label = c("2015-04-01 00:00:00", 
"2015-04-01 00:05:00", "2015-04-01 00:15:00", "2015-04-01 00:25:00", 
"2015-04-01 00:40:00"), class = "factor"), Speed = c(50L, 60L, 
70L, 65L, 40L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

the result should be like below:

```
result <- structure(list(Date_Time = structure(1:9, .Label = c("2015-04-01 00:00:00", 
"2015-04-01 00:05:00", "2015-04-01 00:10:00", "2015-04-01 00:15:00", 
"2015-04-01 00:20:00", "2015-04-01 00:25:00", "2015-04-01 00:30:00", 
"2015-04-01 00:35:00", "2015-04-01 00:40:00"), class = "factor"), 
    Speed = c(50L, 60L, NA, 70L, NA, 65L, NA, NA, 40L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

this is important to me because I want to lead speed by 5 minutes and it would not be true in the first case.

Comment: To clarify, you want to add records to your data frame such that every day has a record that includes every 5 minutes of the day?

Comment: yes, I want to have all the 5 minutes intervals in my new dataframe. @Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a data frame containing date/time sequences 5 minutes apart and then merge with the original data.

```
dataframe$Date_Time <- as.POSIXct(as.character(dataframe$Date_Time))
str(dataframe)

date5 <- data.frame(Date_Time=seq.POSIXt(min(dataframe$Date_Time),
                                         max(dataframe$Date_Time), by="5 mins"))

newdataframe <- merge(dataframe, date5, all=TRUE)
newdataframe

            Date_Time Speed
1 2015-04-01 00:00:00    50
2 2015-04-01 00:05:00    60
3 2015-04-01 00:10:00    NA
4 2015-04-01 00:15:00    70
5 2015-04-01 00:20:00    NA
6 2015-04-01 00:25:00    65
7 2015-04-01 00:30:00    NA
8 2015-04-01 00:35:00    NA
9 2015-04-01 00:40:00    40
```

Comment: I am getting this error when running the code: (Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number)

Comment: Did you copy all of the commands, including this one: `dataframe$Date_Time <- as.POSIXct(as.character(dataframe$Date_Time))`

Comment: it works for my test data! thanks! I will try it on my original data

Answer (score 0):

tidyverse option in one pipeline

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data.frame(Date_Time = seq(from = min(ymd_hms(dataframe$Date_Time)), 
                           to = max(ymd_hms(dataframe$Date_Time)), 
                           by = "5 min")) %>% 
    left_join(., dataframe %>% mutate(Date_Time = ymd_hms(Date_Time)))
```